# Datepicker to only Update Date instead of Time

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have 2 controls: A DatePicker (for the date) and a TextBox (for the time).

Both are linked to the same property `MyDate`. 
On startup the date is now and the time is now, but when I update the date the time changes to `0:00`.
Is there a way to only change the date on the property and leave the time alone?

I understand why and how it is happening but how would I solve this by not altering the property?

```xml
 <DatePicker VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=MyDate, StringFormat='d', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
 </DatePicker>

<dxe:DateEdit Height="25" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" AllowDefaultButton="False" EditValue="{Binding Path=MyDate}" Mask="HH:mm">
    <dxe:DateEdit.StyleSettings>
         <dxe:DateEditPickerStyleSettings/>
    </dxe:DateEdit.StyleSettings>
</dxe:DateEdit>
```

Comment: You should delete this as it is a duplicate of your other post that got an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding Date Only and Time Only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955922/binding-date-only-and-time-only)

Answer (score 3):

The built-in DatePicker control selects only a date without any specific time so I am afraid it makes no sense to try to display the time of the selected date in a TextBox.

You should bind the DatePicker and the TextBox to two different source properties, a `DateTime?` and a `TimeSpan` respectively.

The other option would be to use another control that selects a date and a time, for example this one: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker